# What font face is Apple.com using for the title in their Mac Pro subsite/page?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, css, font-face

If you visit apple's little subpage for the upcoming Mac Pro (http://www.apple.com/mac-pro/), they are using a wonderfully thin yet crisp and legible font for all the title (all rendered as image files).

Any idea what the font family is?  Ive run it through whatthefont, but the results and close but no cigar..

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Myriad Pro is the answer, just figured it out..

Comment: +1 on this. Apple use Myriad Pro for a lot of their site and advertising.

Answer (score 3):

Apple actually uses a custom variation of the Myriad Pro font called "Myriad Set." The custom variation extends the Myriad Pro family with additional weights and glyphs. [See my answer here for sources.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26255/looking-for-myriad-pro-extra-light-used-by-apple/26281#26281)