# Looking for Myriad Pro Extra Light used by Apple

Tags: font-identification, apple

I believe that an extra-light or Thin version of Adobe's Myriad typeface exists, because Apple's been using it on their website.

Here's Myriad Pro Light and Extra Light/Thin used on the iPad Mini page:

[image]

So where do I find it? I can't seem to buy it anywhere. Any help?

Comment: Apple is known to create their own versions of fonts if not their own fonts entirely. It's possible Myriad Pro extra light is an internal Apple font and not available elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see why this has close votes cast as brainstorming/ideagathering. It's asking for a resource of a specific font, not to design with the typeface. I'd say its more of a shopping question, which still might be off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that they use Kozuka Gothic Pro (小塚ゴシック) for those texts. It's a Japanese font that ships with Adobe Creative Suite/Cloud.

You can find the font with the standard name 小塚ゴシック or enable english font names by:
in the preferences > type pane tick the box next to "show font names in english"

The font has 6 weights from EL (Extra Light) to H (Heavy)

Image: Top 2 lines is the source image, bottom 2 lines is Kozuka gothic pro
[image: Top 2 lines is the source image, bottom 2 lines is Kozuka gothic pro]

Comment: wouldn't this only work if the language is set to Japanese though? Clearly the sample image is in English.

Comment: @Scott You're right i didn't specify that those fonts are full Unicode

Comment: Sorry. I don't see your updated images as the same. The stroke weights are obviously different to me. As are the curves and arcs. While **exceptionally** similar, I don't think this is a match at all. It may be an *excellent* substitution, but it's not precisely the same.

Comment: @Scott I'm sure that's just a rendering issue, because the weights looks remarkably similar.

Comment: Kozuka Gothic Pro does not have “fj” ligature, while Myriad Pro does.

Comment: This is...interesting. Looks like Adobe stuck their version of Myriad pro into the typeface in all of the non-Japanese character slots. Interesting find!

Answer (score 3):

Myriad was released in 1992, before the general appearance of extra-light weights, so I'm with Scott on this, it's [EDIT based on Hynes' answer] *a custom variation of it*.

There is a close-ish match available for purchase that is just for web [**at WebINK**](http://app.webink.com/face/2155).

It says it's Myriad Pro *Light*, but if you look at the 24px size one in Chrome (Win 8) it's actually quite a close match:

[image]

Apple is using images for the iPad mini texts in their site, this might be on purpose. There is a ['request' in Typophile](http://typophile.com/node/57577) for a thinner Myriad, you can add your signature to the petition :)

Here's a [**list of extra light fonts**](http://fontfeed.com/archives/extra-thin-ultra-light-fonts/) that might be used as replacement.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about the extra light weight--not the commercially available light weight.

Comment: @DA01 You are correct! Just that this version, when rendered, looks like an extra light instead of light. I'l check the iPad site for license info and see if I can update.

Answer (score 3):

Apple uses a custom variation of Myriad called "Myriad Set."

Sources: [Wikipedia: Typography of Apple, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typography_of_Apple_Inc.#Myriad), [Quora: What font is used in Steve Jobs' presentations?](http://www.quora.com/What-font-is-used-in-Steve-Jobs-presentations)